# set style for above IE8 only

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have one ASP.NET file upload control.Giving custom style to Browse button of file upload control I am write the below code:

```
label.choose:before {
        background: #f07222 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 4.5px 12px;           
        text-transform: uppercase;
        content: 'Browse';
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-margin-before: -2px;
        -webkit-padding-start: 19px;
        -webkit-padding-end: 19px;
    }

 <label class="choose">
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_DataFile" runat="server" />
 </label>
```

It's work fine in FireFox and Chrome.But in IE browse button display right side of input text.Where in FF and Chrome it's display at left side.So my code is not working in IE.
If I add

```
margin-left:141px;
```

only for IE than works but How to add this property only for IE browsers?
I have IE11.And I want to do this for above IE8.When I R&D about that I found conditional style for IE but it's not work in above IE9.

**Is it possible to apply custom style only File upload button ?If yes than please give me code example for this?**

Any solution for add style only for IE?
Or any alternative way to do this?

Comment: http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani can you please give syntax or code for add margin like this way.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Comment: `-ms-input-placeholder, :root .label.choose:before {
     margin-left:141px;
}`    is it right?? not working in IE11

Comment: A standard pseudo-element selector contains double colon ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for my question!!!

Only write following code for set css style for IE.

```
_:-ms-input-placeholder, :root .choose:before {                
            margin-left: 141px;               
        }
```

And This is working fine for IE11..!!